# Embedded Flash player in a Facebook newsfeed post sometimes opens a new window instead of playing inline

Tags: facebook, flash, embed, facebook-opengraph

My team is running the music portal (songs, music videos, etc.) [SongDew](http://www.songdew.com), and we're having trouble with letting our users share content on Facebook. When users share songs on Facebook, our application embeds a Flash player object in the newsgeed post. The post that results from sharing a song has an image in it with a play button on top of the image: when someone clicks the play button, the image expands, turns into a Flash player, and plays the song.

The bug that we're running into is that sometimes when a user clicks the play button, the browser opens a new window and loads the actual Flash source.

You can see the problem live on the site right now - go to [SongDew](http://www.songdew.com), sign up with a Facebook ID, share a song on Facebook, and try clicking on the newsfeed post it generates.

As far as I can tell, we've added all of the OpenGraph tags required. The content gets shared correctly and a post shows up in newsfeeds - it's just that the play button opens a new window of the Flash source instead of playing the Flash inline.

How can I fix this bug so that the Flash plays inline instead of opening a new window with the media source?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `og:url` meta tag, that should make the parser's job easier. Also check the [url linter/debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object)'s output, `og:message` not recognized, probably needs to be `og:description` instead.

Since youtube seem to be working, try recreate [their tags](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meOCdyS7ORE).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..I have added the og:url tag and removed og:message tag.And checked the linter tool.I have tested sharing the song using different facebook user ids.But for only few facebook users i can see play icon and song is being played inline, and for others i dont even see the play icon...please help me out..

Comment: Could be bug in facebook or some strange corner case of preferences. Also facebook caches urls it crawl, try sharing brand new ones. Youtube links work for the users rerporting issues with your site?

Answer (score 0):

`og:type:video.other` is missing in your og tags

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but i am trying to share the song not video,also og:type:video.other is only required if we want to publish actions on facebook wall..you can also check the website www.songdew.com and share a song (music) not videos.